# simultanious perl system calls on windows

Tags: perl

Trying to find a way to have a perl script run 4 other perl scripts on windows and then once all are done, kick off a 5th script. I have checked out a bunch of things but none seem straight forward. Suggestions welcome.  The scripts are going to run on a windows box. scripts 1-4 need to finish first before starting script 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Proc::Background;

my @commands = (
  ['./Files1.exe ALL'],
  ['./Files2.exe ALL'],
  ['./Files3.exe ALL'],
  ['./Files4.exe ALL'],
); 

my @procs = map {  Proc::Background->new(@$_) } @commands;

$_->wait for @procs;

system 'echo', 'CSCProc', '--pidsAndExitStatus', map { $_->pid, $_->wait } @procs;

`mergefiles.exe`;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Accept answers to your other questions
2. `use threads`

   2.1. kick of the 4 scripts:

   ```
   my @scripts = qw(... commands ...);
   my @jobs = ();
   foreach my $script (@scripts) {
     my $job = threads->create( sub {
       system($script);
     });
     push @jobs, $job;
   }
   ```

   2.2. Wait for completition

   ```
   $_->join() foreach @jobs;
   ```

   2.3. Kick off the last script

#### Edit

As you indicated that my solution didn't work for you, I fired up my Windoze box, taught me to use this horrible cmd.exe and wrote following test script. It is a bit simplified over over the above solution, but *does* meet your requirements about sequentiality etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; use threads;

my @scripts = (
  q(echo "script 1 reporting"),
  q(perl -e "sleep 2; print qq{hi there! This is script 2 reporting\n}"),
  q(echo "script 3 reporting"),
);

my @jobs = map {
  threads->create(sub{
    system($_);
  });
} @scripts;

$_->join foreach @jobs;

print "finished all my jobs\n";

system q(echo "This is the last job");
```

I used this command to execute the script (on Win7 with Strawberry Perl v5.12.2):

```
C:\...>perl stackoverflow.pl
```

And this is the output:

```
"script 1 reporting"
"script 3 reporting"
hi there! This is script 2 reporting
finished all my jobs
"This is the last job"
```

So how on earth does this not work? I would very much like to learn circumventing Perl's pitfalls the next time I write a script on a non-GNU system, so please enlighten me about what can go wrong.

Comment: This did not work but thanks.  I am not sure what you menat about accept answers.  Most of my questions I have asked where not answered or the answer did not work for me.  I will be more on top or responding to the help that is given and accept answers that work.

Comment: @user1279586 Im sorry to hear that, sadly I can't help you with Ruby… Well, my code worked for me, and Perl should be hiding the fact that we are using different OSes with such a simple script. I wrote a Windoze test, and it worked fine. Can you please compare your results?

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, using `fork()` in ActiveState Perl doesn't always run the process sequentially.  The threaded simulation of `fork()` used there seems to start all the processes, get it to a certain point, then run them one at a time. This applies even on multicore CPUs. I think Strawberry Perl is compiled the same way. Also, keep in mind that `fork()` is still being used for backticks and `system()`, it's just abstracted away.

If you use Cygwin Perl on Windows, it will run through Cygwin's own `fork()` call and things will parallelize properly. However, Cygwin is slower in other ways.

Comment: The scheduling is done by the OS, not Perl. Yes, ActiveState and Strawberry use the same emulation.

Comment: @ikegami: doesn't really matter where the effect is coming from--it's an issue to be aware of.